# Product of sums of all subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Input: set of N integers

Output: product of sum of all subsets of input set

e.g. for input {1,2,3}, output should be 1 * 2 * 3 * (1+2) * (1+3) * (2+3) * (1+2+3) = 2160.

Could anyone suggest if you can implement such an algorithm optimally? (in polynomial time - if this is possible).

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1 * 2 * 3 * (1+2) * (1+3) * (2+3) * (1+2+3) = 2160?

Comment: Yes. Sorry - my mistake.

Comment: For what it's worth, these numbers grow ridiculously quickly. For example, $$\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \rightarrow 18458571748581562066056556704775089466054740541440000000000000$$.

Comment: Considering there are $2^n-1$ non-empty subsets of a set with $n$ elements, the most trivial solution would be to just cycle through each subset, calculating the sum for each subset and then calculating the product of the sums.  This would run in $O(n2^n)$ time.  I don't immediately see a shortcut, but its likely someone with more experience with this may know a better way.

Comment: @JMoravitz if it wasn't just a random set there may be faster ways finite arithmetic progressions etc. to get the sums.